# Looking for a Finnish bread name and recipe

Tags: bread, fish, finnish-cuisine

About 20 years ago, I went to Finland to visit a friend and I had the opportunity to stay with her and her parents.

They treated me with home-made meals. It was really good.

I remember that they have a special bread which serves as a meal. It was filled with small fishes and an unknown sauce. When you cut it open, the content was flowing outside of the crust.

I asked my friend about it but she couldn't find an answer. I'd love to find the name of that bread / dish.

Comment: Recipe requests are off topic here but you should be able to find one easily with an internet search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like kalakukko. From  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalakukko) :

> Kalakukko is a traditional food from the Finnish region of Savonia made from fish baked inside a loaf of bread. The Cornish pasty from Cornwall has the same basic idea of complete packed lunch. Kalakukko is especially popular in Kuopio, capital city of the Northern Savonia region. Kuopio is home to many kalakukko bakeries. The city also hosts an annual kalakukko baking contest.[1]
>
> Traditionally, kalakukko is prepared with rye flour (like ruisleipä), although wheat is often added to make the dough more pliable. The filling consists of fish, pork and bacon, and is seasoned with salt (unless the pork is already salted). After being baked for several hours, traditionally in a masonry oven, kalakukko looks much like a large loaf of rye bread. If prepared correctly, bones of the fish soften and the meat and fish juices cook thoroughly inside the bread. This results in a moist filling.